# How can I reformat internal storage on Android?

Tags: internal-storage, twrp, partitions

I'd like some assistance with formatting the internal storage of my phone.
I've managed to unbrick it and to flash TWRP recovery but I can see that capacity of the internal storage is only 33 MB which is clearly wrong. Before I started doing all this it had GB of capacity not MB. So clearly I need to fix this. I tried to use Windows's disk manager
but the manager isn't detecting the phone or the storage.

Can I have some guidance here ? It's Meizu 5 pro. Any helpful input much appreciated.

`cat /proc/partitions` gives me:

```
major   minor  #blocks  name
   8       0   61071360  sda
   8       1   1024      sda1
   8       2   256       sda2
   8       3   256       sda3
 259       0   4096      sda21
 259       1   8192      sda22
 259       2   2048      sda23
 259       3   4096      sda24
 259       4   4096      sda25
 259       5   24576     sda26
 259       6   32768     sda27
 259       7   32768     sda28
 259       8   20480     sda29
 259       9   20480     sda30
 259      10   20480     sda31
 259      11   20480     sda32
 259      12   20480     sda33
 259      13   2621440   sda41
 259      14   524288    sda42
 259      15   57663468  sda43
 259      16   38912     sda44
   8      16   4096      sdb
   8      32   4096      sdc
 179      0    30253056  mmcblk0
 179      1    30252032  mmcblk0p1
```

`ls -ld /dev/block/bootdevice/by-name/*` gives me "No such file or directory"

**Note:**

The phone hasn't got any OS running at the moment.

[image]

[image]

I managed to use ADB and fdisk to get a list of locations (`fdisk /dev/block/sda`) in the phone. Then I pressed "p" for a print out.
I marked locations or partitions in question. Cache takes up all the storage whereas "userdata" gets only 38MB. In advanced mode where I get to make changes when I press "p" again I get different output. I don't understand this.

**Update:**

I modified the partition table to make it look like the way I need:

[image]

The problem I'm dealing with right now is that the phone doesn't want to mount the devices. Can't get it to mount system, cache, userdata.
I made sure "userdata" is still vfat and cache is ext4. Order number of partitions have changed though. Does that matter ?

**latest update:**

[image]

Looks like I was right for once. When I ran `mount -a` to mount all devices I got error because devices are assigned to different partition number.

[image]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106300/discussion-on-question-by-the-one-how-can-i-reformat-internal-storage-on-android).

Answer (score 0):

check your file system type is ext4 or f2fs with `mount`

in TWRP you can format from command line (beware this is factory reset /data and /sdcard is lost)

```
adb shell
umount /sdcard /data
mount -r /system
mount -r /vendor
export PATH=/system/bin:/sbin
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/system/lib64:/system/vendor/lib64:/vendor/lib64:/system/lib:/system/vendor/lib:/vendor/lib
/system/bin/sh
mke2fs -t ext4 /dev/block/sda44 [fs-size]
or
mkfs.f2fs /dev/block/sda44 [fs-size]
```

Note: fs-size is optional. depending on encryption method you may reserve last -16384 bytes for encryption footer. in this case calculate sectors

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106301/discussion-on-answer-by-alecxs-how-can-i-reformat-internal-storage-on-android).